# Regex Find Number Among Special Characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new to regex with python, and am having trouble with this problem.
I have a string that contains this substring `</span></td><td class="Ta(c) Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" colspan="6" data-reactid="(some unknown number from 0-100000)"><strong data-reactid="(some unknown number from 0-100000)">(the number i need)</`

I want the script to return whatever is in (the number i need) position.
ie. if the string contained `</span></td><td class="Ta(c) Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" colspan="6" data-reactid="223"><strong data-reactid="96456">1.001</`, the program would return `1.001`

So far, i tried using regex like so; `re.findall('Jan 02, 2020</span></td><td class="Ta\(c\) Py\(10px\) Pstart\(10px\)" colspan="6" data-reactid="\d"><strong data-reactid="\d">')`, but with no luck
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Edit the question to show what you have tried. You can play around with regex at http://regex101.com

Comment: edited to add what i have tried

Comment: What part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is

```
x = '''</span></td><td class="Ta(c) Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" colspan="6" data-reactid="223"><strong data-reactid="96456">1.001</'''
re.findall(r'</span></td><td class="Ta\(c\) Py\(10px\) Pstart\(10px\)" colspan="6" data-reactid="[\d]+"><strong data-reactid="[\d]+">(.*)</', x)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve my problem, this finds all substrings that contain `<strong data-reactid="[\d]+">(.*)<\/` instead of all substrings that contain `</span></td><td class="Ta(c) Py(10px) Pstart(10px)" colspan="6" data-reactid="223"><strong data-reactid="96456">`